# django MPTT model and applying Fixture

Tags: django, python-2.7, mptt, django-fixtures

I'm using django MPTT model.

I subclass MPTT model, but then try to add fixture to the custom model with supplied initial_data in JSON.

The parent TreeForeignKey is optional (blank=True, null=True)

When I apply a JSON fixture from initial_data, it asks to supply the fields "lft", "rght", "tree_id", "level".

```
ie: may not be NULL
```

...when running python manage.py syncdb

These are fields from MPTT.

Is there a way to exclude this or get around this from the fixture data?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried to add "parent":None to each "record" in the fixture after I supplied some arbitrary data to the "lft", "rght" etc...but the parent field of type TreeForeignKey is still populated after I apply the fixture.

Comment: Did you try to define `TreeForeignKey` to `self`? Like they have in the [docs] (http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/tutorial.html) _You must define a parent field which is a TreeForeignKey to 'self'. A TreeForeignKey is just a regular ForeignKey that renders form fields differently in the admin and a few other places._

Comment: yes, it has always been set to self. thanks for the response